# Can i Remove copyright text wordpress.org theme

Tags: themes, copyright

Hope you're doing great. i am using a theme wordpress.org that's shopstore ( https://wordpress.org/themes/shopstore/ )

Can i remove the copyright text from the theme for my own usess?
[image]

Thanks

Comment: Why do you ask this here? Why don't you ask this in this plugin's support forum? Please search the plugin's forum yourself first, read this plugin's license yourself first, read this plugin's README yourself first. Please add what you found out in all these places to your question if it still is unclear to you. Many thanks

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the theme license allows, you can remove the footer text and link.

Comment: you can remove/edit it at anytime. question is should you or shouldn't